# How to bind a yml object to a field declared as an interface that the object implements?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have this java hierarchy:

```
interface Foo {
    // methods
}

@Data
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
class Bar implements Foo {
    // override interface methods
}

@Data
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
class Baz implements Foo {
    // override interface methods
}

@Data
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
class FooConfig {
    List<Foo> stuff = new Arraylist<>;
}
```

and this application.yml

```
foo:
    stuff[0]: { Bar }
    stuff[1]: { Baz }
```

But this does not work. I get this exception

> Failed to instantiate [Foo]: Specified class is an interface

When i change `List<Foo> stuff` to `List<Bar> stuff` it only works for `stuff[0]: { Bar }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any configuration properties/yml files to achieve this. Spring is intelligent enough to detect implementations of an interface.

Just do this.

```
@Data
@Configuration
class FooConfig {
    @Autowired
    List<Foo> stuff;
}
```

Spring will automagically search all the implementations of interface `Foo` and autowire it.

**NOTE:**  All the implementations should be a bean(in your case you have `@Component` on both Bar and Baz, so it should be fine)

You can even do

```
@Data
@Configuration
class FooConfig {
   @Autowired
   Map<String, Foo> stuffMap;
}
```

In this case, spring will create a map, with key as bean names(by default it will be bar and baz)

Comment: you need to have `@Autowired`. Updated my answer

Comment: Ok, this approach works but field injection is not recommended by the spring team. Also it does pull all Foo implementations into the List<Foo> therefore it's not really configurable, that is I can not exclude certain implementations. Lets say I want to run only Bar on one app-instance and Baz on another app-instance but this approach will always put both into the List<Foo>

Comment: you can still constructor inject configurations but really a configuration is so tightly coupled to the spring ecosystem any argument for doing so drops off.  As for running one on different instances use profiles or some other conditional initiazation of the beans.

Comment: As @DarrenForsythe pointed out. This is just a snippet. You can change this to constructor injection in a matter of seconds. That is not a big deal. And with respect to conditional injection,  Springboot provides many different ways, checkout `@Profile`, `@Condition`, `ConditionalOnExpression` ...... Another point is specifying bean name in yml file is not a good idea. If someone happens to change the classname and forget's to change in yml file, then the whole functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Another point is, you would put something which is configurable in your properties/yml file, not something which is so tightly coupled with classname